# "Клаксон"

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Клаксон", как обозначение сигнального устройства автомобиля, является сейчас устаревшим или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не вижу причин объявлять устаревшим. Да и в словарях нет соответствующих помет.